# SQL Server 2014 sqlcmd not recognized

Tags: sql-server, database

I installed SQL Server 2014 32-bit database to Windows 10.

I want to connect to the server with `sqlcmd` but the prompt cmd does not recognize the command.

How to solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Its not in your path. On my machine sqlcmd is in (SQL Server 2012):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn
```

you and either add the folder where sqlcmd.exe is located into your path or you can execute (on my machine) by running:

'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe

If you have other versions of SQL Server (or Sybase which has its own, very powerful, version of SQLCMD) you may find it convenient to run sqlcmd by specify the folder where it is located.

Open a command window

Then run this (including the ' quote at the start of the line:

```
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe <sql cmd values>
```

Answer (score 1):

< Install Directory >\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn Should have sqlcmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem.

Solution:

- Open SQL Sever COnfiguration Manager
- Navigate to SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration and click on Client protocols
- Enable Shared Memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes
- Do this for SQL server network Configuration too
- Lunch SQLCMD.EXE from ..\110\Tools\Binn
- restart computer
- Everything will work fine ;)